# Swift: how to set range of photos between 2 dates?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, photosframework

I want to get photos from Photo Library from 1 of January to 1 of May
How can I do that

my code is for all photos:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [ NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true) ]
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [creationDate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624776-creationdate) attribute, so you can extend your predicate to filter dates:

```
(creationDate >= %@) AND (creationDate <= %@)
```

So your predicate should look something like the following

```
options.predicate = NSPredicate(
  format: "mediaType = %d AND (creationDate >= %@) AND (creationDate <= %@)", 
  PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue, 
  fromDate as NSDate, 
  toDate as NSDate
)
```

Comment: `BETWEEN` is viable for `NSPredicate` queries.

Comment: yep, agree. just trying to use more obvious way, because it's not clear what included in `BETWEEN`. on the other hand you got specific operators `>=`, `>`, etc

Comment: Argument type 'Date' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg' @rkyr

Comment: yep, since it's NSPredicate you need to cast your date to `NSDate`. will update an answer in a sec